# How to set iot Hub (or AzFunction) to send message to a IOT edge input route?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to send C2D messages using Azure,

however, I can’t get all the information in the Microsoft Documentation (and internet in general) on "How to send message from the cloud to an IOT-EDGE module input ?"
I have already found some bits of answer, but I can’t find this last piece of information.

> step 1 send message :

I found a bunch of good examples and sample explaining how to send C2D message to a regular IOT device. but none on an edge one? Is it even possible ?

> step 2 receiver:

I have an IOT-Edge custom module that have an output to the "$upstream". For the input I tried :

`"FROM $upstream INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/edgeModule/inputs/input1\")"  and as expected it doesn’t work.`

Do you have any leads ?

thanks.

*PS: English is not my native language, Sorry for the mistakes if found any.*

Answer (score 0):

IoT Edge modules can only receive Direct Method calls but not async Cloud-to-device messages. You can find examples how to implement the DM calls for instance here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iotedge-end2end-messageflow

Comment: I'll look into that, thank you for your answer (If I manage to make it work, I'll close question)